# Iframe : How to display Type and ID

Tags: javascript, html, css, iframe

I am a beginner with JavaScript and trying to make an iframe.

The problem of my iframe is when I click on a link I want to show the id and the type in the iframe.

Can someone help me how to fix this problem ?

[image: something like this]

```
<script src="jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
    function SetIframe(Type, ID)
        {
        $("#DriveFrame").prop.('src')// i have no idea what to put after 'src' :( 
        }
</script>

<body>


<ul>
    <li><a href="javascript:SetIframe('Medewerkers', '1000');" target="lijst">Medewerker 1000</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:SetIframe('Medewerkers', '1001');" target="lijst">Medewerker 1001</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:SetIframe('Medewerkers', '2001');" target="lijst">Medewerker 2001</a></li>
    <li><a href="javascript:SetIframe('Kantoor', '101');" target="lijst">Kantoor 101</a></li>
</ul>
<hr>
<center>
<iframe name="lijst" id="DriveFrame" width="500" height="520"></iframe>
</center>
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Lrynnuhm/1/

Comment: Read the documentation on how to use [jquery `prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)

Comment: $("#DriveFrame").prop('src',"ifra.html?Type=" + Type + "&ID=" + ID)
if i use this line of code it shows the whole page again but i just want it to print the user type and id

Comment: I believe you should be using attr() and not prop() to change the src.

Comment: Why are you using an iframe if you aren't loading a URL into it?

Comment: @Quentin Are you sure? You can use it without loading an URL http://codepen.io/kranzy/pen/GjQWwv

Comment: @LearnHowToBeTransparent — You *can* but that doesn't mean you should. It complicates things for (in this specific context) no apparent benefit over just modifying the DOM of a div..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's as easy as setting the src attribute of the iframe to a data:text/html URI (to inject html to iframe)

So the code is:

```
DriveFrame = $("#DriveFrame")[0];
DriveFrame.src="data:text/html,<h1>[Type="+Type+"]<br>ID="+ID+"";
```

Live fiddle here:

```
// https://jsfiddle.net/Lrynnuhm/3/
```

Explanation:

`$("#DriveFrame")[0];` get the DOM element of the iframe (I mean, not JQuery, I hate using `.prop()` in the next step to change the URI)

Then, I inject HTML to iframe using [`data:text/html,<html code>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs) (you can use `DriveFrame.contentDocument.write()`, but when you click another link, the text just goes under existing text.)

Comment: Ahh thnx it worked. 1 last question in your fiddle u dont use DriveFrame = $("#DriveFrame")[0]; should i use it or not ? i am a bit confused

Comment: Ok, because when you set id(DriveFrame), the ID is already a variable with value = the iframe's DOM element (only if you follow JS variable name rules - no hyphen, no space, no leading number...) @selimoruc

Comment: brackets missing in id ;)

Answer (score -1):

Try this see if this help :

```
<!doctype html>
<html>

  <title>Selim's Drive test</title>
  <script>
    function SetIframe(Type, ID){
      document.getElementById('DriveFrame').contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML = "<p>["+Type+"]</p><p>["+ID+"]</p>";
    }
  </script>

  <body>


    <ul>
      <li><a href="javascript:SetIframe('Medewerkers', '1000');" target="lijst">Medewerker 1000</a></li>
      <li><a href="javascript:SetIframe('Medewerkers', '1001');" target="lijst">Medewerker 1001</a></li>
      <li><a href="javascript:SetIframe('Medewerkers', '2001');" target="lijst">Medewerker 2001</a></li>
      <li><a href="javascript:SetIframe('Kantoor', '101');" target="lijst">Kantoor 101</a></li>
    </ul>
    <hr>
    <center>
      <iframe name="lijst" id="DriveFrame" width="500" height="520"></iframe>
    </center>
  </body>
</html>
```

Updated jsfiddle here:

// https://jsfiddle.net/Lrynnuhm/5/